# Unable to add subquery expression in Group By - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query like below,

```
select a,b,c, (select h from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b) as alias_column, d
from table 
group by a,b,c, (select h from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b) , d
```

I am getting the error like,

```
ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed here
22818. 00000 -  "subquery expressions not allowed here"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a subquery expression where these
           are not supported.
*Action:   Rewrite the statement without the subquery expression.
Error at Line: 84 Column: 2
```

I think this is because `where clause` in the subquery that is added in the `group by`

See the subquery, `(select * from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b)` has `a` and `b`  fields from the parent table.

Please help.

Comment: Try to replace subquery in group by with alias_column

Comment: It is not working .. When I google it says I have to put all the subquery in group by

Comment: There are multiple tables are joined in the subquery. I have not mentioned that in the questions.

Comment: Would you mind to setup http://sqlfiddle.com/ to debug your issue?

Comment: you group using a subquery? it cant be done .. literally grouping some data, is wht you have from ur _FROM_ and _WHERE_ clauses..

Comment: Your subquery select * from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b must retur only one value.

Comment: Side issue, but why aren't you just doing a join to the second table, instead of using a subquery at all?

Answer (score 0):

If the subquery (`select * from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b`)
is returning only one value then this should work:

```
select * from
(select a,b,c, (select * from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b) as alias_column, d
from table) 
group by a,b,c, alias_column , d
```

But if the subquery (`select * from table 1 where field = a and field2 = b`)
is not returning only one value then you will get below error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Comment: @Sahal ok, did you tried with the query I suggested?

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a group by when no aggregate functions are involved?

Use `DISTINCT` instead, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,
       (select * from table 1
        where field = a and field2 = b) as alias_column, d
from table
```